# Error in WrapperBeanGenerator : Not creating ASM Type for type

Tags: java, linux, web-services, soap, copy

I'm trying to use a Copy Web Service client to retrieve a soap object on a Linux server. However I keep getting this error trace below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not creating ASM Type for type = byte[]
at                  com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.WrapperBeanGenerator.getASMType(WrapperBeanGenerator.java:434)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.WrapperBeanGenerator.collectRequestWrapperMembers(WrapperBeanGenerator.java:297)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.WrapperBeanGenerator.createRequestWrapperBean(WrapperBeanGenerator.java:239)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getRequestWrapperClass(RuntimeModeler.java:279)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:673)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:611)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:400)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:239)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:710)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:698)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:330)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:313)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:295)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:112)
at actuals.com.microsoft.sharepoint.webservices.Copy.getCopySoap(Copy.java:56)
```

And below is the code being run:

```
public CopySoap getCopySoap() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Creating a CopySoap instance...");
    Copy service = new Copy(new URL("https://ts.kompany.com/sites/Global/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx?wsdl"),
            new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", "Copy"));
    CopySoap copySoap = service.getCopySoap();
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) copySoap;
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, userName);
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://ts.kompany.com/sites/Global/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx");
    System.out.println(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY.getBytes()+""+ BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY.getBytes());
    return copySoap;
}
```

It fails on the line:

```
CopySoap copySoap = service.getCopySoap();
```

The CopySoap class is as follows:

```
package actuals.com.microsoft.sharepoint.webservices;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.ws.Holder;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6
 * Generated source version: 2.1
 * 
 */
@WebService(name = "CopySoap", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface CopySoap {


    /**
     * 
     * @param results
     * @param copyIntoItemsLocalResult
     * @param sourceUrl
     * @param destinationUrls
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "CopyIntoItemsLocal", action = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CopyIntoItemsLocal")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "CopyIntoItemsLocal", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", className = "com.microsoft.sharepoint.webservices.CopyIntoItemsLocal")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "CopyIntoItemsLocalResponse", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", className = "com.microsoft.sharepoint.webservices.CopyIntoItemsLocalResponse")
    public void copyIntoItemsLocal(
        @WebParam(name = "SourceUrl", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/")
        String sourceUrl,
        @WebParam(name = "DestinationUrls", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/")
        DestinationUrlCollection destinationUrls,
        @WebParam(name = "CopyIntoItemsLocalResult", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
        Holder<Long> copyIntoItemsLocalResult,
        @WebParam(name = "Results", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
        Holder<CopyResultCollection> results);

    /**
     * 
     * @param stream
     * @param results
     * @param copyIntoItemsResult
     * @param sourceUrl
     * @param destinationUrls
     * @param fields
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "CopyIntoItems", action = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CopyIntoItems")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "CopyIntoItems", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", className = "com.microsoft.sharepoint.webservices.CopyIntoItems")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "CopyIntoItemsResponse", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", className = "com.microsoft.sharepoint.webservices.CopyIntoItemsResponse")
    public void copyIntoItems(
        @WebParam(name = "SourceUrl", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/")
        String sourceUrl,
        @WebParam(name = "DestinationUrls", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/")
        DestinationUrlCollection destinationUrls,
        @WebParam(name = "Fields", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/")
        FieldInformationCollection fields,
        @WebParam(name = "Stream", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/")
        byte[] stream,
        @WebParam(name = "CopyIntoItemsResult", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
        Holder<Long> copyIntoItemsResult,
        @WebParam(name = "Results", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
        Holder<CopyResultCollection> results);

    /**
     * 
     * @param getItemResult
     * @param stream
     * @param url
     * @param fields
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetItem", action = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetItem")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "GetItem", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", className = "com.microsoft.sharepoint.webservices.GetItem")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "GetItemResponse", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", className = "com.microsoft.sharepoint.webservices.GetItemResponse")
    public void getItem(
        @WebParam(name = "Url", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/")
        String url,
        @WebParam(name = "GetItemResult", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
        Holder<Long> getItemResult,
        @WebParam(name = "Fields", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
        Holder<FieldInformationCollection> fields,
        @WebParam(name = "Stream", targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
        Holder<byte[]> stream);

}
```

My code works fine when I run it locally in Eclipse on Windows 7, but over on a Linux server, it gives me this error. Does anyone know what it means or how I can resolve this error?

Comment: Can you post the WSDL and/or the CopySoap class?

Comment: Have added the CopySoap class to the original post.

Comment: I can see the parameter with the byte array (byte[] "Stream") in copyIntoItems, shouldn't it be a holder? can you check in WSDL if it's declared as xs:base64Binary or what?

Comment: @SimoneGianni I can see there is the following entry in a 's:complexType' tag? 
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Stream" type="s:base64Binary" />

Comment: Anyone know what might be causing this issue? It is still persisting :(

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be to switch to a different Java version on your Linux machine:

I had exactly the same problem (devloping on Windows 7 / execution on Linux, same error stack trace).

On my Linux server I was using "JDK 1.6.0_22-b04" and I figured out that there seems to be a bug inside of the standard java library "rt.jar". After switching to "JDK 1.7.0_51-b03", it worked.